# WP7 JSON returning list within a list

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm trying to return json data from a list within a list. The data is being pulled using a webclient and deserialized using JSON.NET. I'd like to return a name and image from the "featuredCharts" list which is within the "Results" list. Here is part of the json data I'm referring to.

```
"results":{
  "featuredCharts":[
     {
        "id":46082,
        "type":"chart",
        "name":"Exclusives On Beatport - Week 5",
        "slug":"exclusives-on-beatport-week-5",
        "description":"",
        "publishDate":"2012-01-30",
        "price":{
           "code":"usd",
           "symbol":"$",
           "value":2390
        },
        "audioFormatFee":{
           "wav":{
              "code":"usd",
              "symbol":"$",
              "value":1000
           },
           "aiff":{
              "code":"usd",
              "symbol":"$",
              "value":1000
           }
        },
        "genres":[
           {
              "id":11,
              "name":"Tech House",
              "slug":"tech-house",
              "type":"genre"
           },
           {
              "id":5,
              "name":"House",
              "slug":"house",
              "type":"genre"
           },
           {
              "id":17,
              "name":"Electro House",
              "slug":"electro-house",
              "type":"genre"
           },
           {
              "id":15,
              "name":"Progressive House",
              "slug":"progressive-house",
              "type":"genre"
           }
        ],
        "images":{
           "small":{
              "width":30,
              "height":30,
              "url":"http:\/\/geo-media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951247.jpg",
              "secureUrl":"https:\/\/media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951247.jpg"
           },
           "medium":{
              "width":60,
              "height":60,
              "url":"http:\/\/geo-media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951248.jpg",
              "secureUrl":"https:\/\/media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951248.jpg"
           },
           "large":{
              "width":130,
              "height":130,
              "url":"http:\/\/geo-media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951249.jpg",
              "secureUrl":"https:\/\/media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/40\/4951249.jpg"
           },
           "xlarge":{
              "width":500,
              "height":500,
              "url":"http:\/\/geo-media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/50\/4951250.jpg",
              "secureUrl":"https:\/\/media.beatport.com\/items\/imageCatalog\/4000000\/900000\/50000\/1000\/200\/50\/4951250.jpg"
           }
        },
        "chartOwner":null
     },
```

My classes are currently setup like this.

```
public class NewReleasesCharts //Root Object
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<ResultHome> results = new List<ResultHome>();

    public IEnumerator<ResultHome> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class ResultHome
{
    public List<FeaturedCharts> featuredCharts { get; set; }
    public List<FeaturedReleases> featuredReleases { get; set; }
}

public class FeaturedCharts
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public ChartImages chartImages { get; set; }
}

public class ChartImages
{
    public ChartSmall chartSmall { get; set; }
    public ChartMedium chartMedium { get; set; }
    public ChartLarge chartLarge { get; set; }
}

public class ChartMedium
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string secureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part I'm stuck on. After deserializing the data I thought about using nested foreach loops, but i currently get an error "Cannot convert type Beatport.Classes.ResultHome' to 'Beatport.Classes.FeaturedCharts". Here is the code.

**UPDATE** I updated my code per ColinE's answer and I am now getting a NullReferenceException error on the inner foreach loop.

```
    // Deserialize home page data
    void jsonHome_GetDataCompleted(object snder, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            NewReleasesCharts homeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleasesCharts>(e.Result);

            try
            {
                // Nested foreach loops to dispaly data
                foreach (ResultHome rc in homeData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (FeaturedCharts fc in rc.featuredCharts)
                        {
                            // TODO: return name and image of chart
                            string name = fc.name;
                            listCharts.Items.Add(name);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm still a beginner when it comes to c# so i'm not sure if the nested foreach loops is the right way to go. An example of how to do this properly would give me something to build off of, as i'll need to do this in other parts of my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop is iterating over the same  data as the first. You need to iterate over the `featuredCharts` property of the variable being iterated in the outer loop:

```
    try
    {
        NewReleasesCharts homeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleasesCharts>(e.Result);

        // foreach loop to dispaly data
        foreach (ResultHome rc in homeData)
        {
            foreach (FeaturedCharts fc in rc.featuredCharts)
            {
                // return name and image of chart
            }
        }
    }
```

To solve this kind of problem in the feature, try setting breakpoints in your code and running in debug mode. You can then inspect the type of each variable to determine what you have done wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Colin. Using your example I am getting a NullReferenceException on the inner foreach loop. See update for new code.